# how to write host for chrome extension native message in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Now, I develop a Chrome Extension need [nativeMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)。Doc has a Python host demo, I now need a Nodejs demo.

I find a repo: https://github.com/jdiamond/chrome-native-messaging, but its demo(my_host.js) occur `Failed to connect: Native host has exited`.

Or，how to tranlate this python [demo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host.zip) into Nodejs.

thx

Comment: There are other working examples of using node.js for native messaging. Like [this](https://github.com/andy-portmen/native-client).

Comment: thanks, but it occur error still: Failed to connect: Native host has exited.

Comment: Then the problem is probably caused by something else, not the native app.

Comment: I'm sorry I know it's rude, but I don't seem to be able to help it. Excuse me, you have the simplest way of Nodejs ? Even if it's just a few functions...

Comment: @riskers what OS are you using? I've managed to get Native Messaging working in macOS, but not Windows or Linux.

Comment: my macOS verison is 10.13.6